# Error al compilar programa en Ada: "cannot find -lpthread"

Tags: ada, gnat, emacs

Estoy usando Emacs para programar en [ada](/questions/tagged/ada) utilizando el compilador GNAT.

Y me tira el siguiente error al intentar compilar:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "c:/Users/Sergio/Favorites/Desktop/Universidad/Ada/" -*-
Compilation started at Sat Sep 03 01:21:40

gnatmake -d hola.adb
completed 1 out of 2 (50%)...
completed 2 out of 2 (100%)...
gnatbind -x hola.ali
gnatlink hola.ali
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gnatlink: error when calling C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
gnatmake: *** link failed.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 4 at Sat Sep 03 01:21:43
```

---

El código que intento compilar es un simple hola mundo:

```
with Text_IO;

procedure Hola is
begin
    Text_Io.Put_Line("hola");
end Hola;
```

y el comando que utilizo es `gnatmake hola.abd`

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Probaste reinstalar gcc?

Answer (score 0):

El programa está mal escrito. Te lo pongo bien:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Hola is
begin
    Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line("hola");
end Hola;
```